# with @tailwindcss/forms border responsive not work

Tags: tailwind-css

why with @tailwindcss/forms plugin border responsive doesn't work? border work fine

```
<div class="border"></div>
```

but md:border or lg:border doesn't work.

```
<div class="md:border"></div>
```

Can you explane me why?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share your `tailwind.config.js` file as well? It's possible that the responsive variants got deactivated and that'd be where to check.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say given what you've provided. I believe there's a default border applied with the forms plugin, but it should only affect form elements.

You could try

```css
<div class="border-0 md:border"></div>
```

to deactivate the border on smaller breakpoints. That would show you if there's a default border coming from somewhere else - unless it's CSS with a more specific selector. (It that works I'd recommend hunting down the CSS that's causing that default border.)